# Getting error "Get http://localhost:9443/metrics: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9443: connect: connection refused"

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, prometheus

I'm trying to configure Prometheus and Grafana with my Hyperledger fabric v1.4 network to analyze the peer and chaincode mertics. I've mapped peer container's port `9443` to my host machine's port `9443` after following this [documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operations_service.html#peer). I've also changed the `provider` entry to `prometheus` under `metrics` section in `core.yml` of peer. I've configured prometheus and grafana in `docker-compose.yml` in the following way.

```
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.6.1
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
    - ./prometheus/:/etc/prometheus/
    - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
    - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
    - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
    - '--web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries'
    - '--web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles'
    - '--storage.tsdb.retention=200h'
    - '--web.enable-lifecycle'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
    - 9090:9090
    networks:
    - basic
    labels:
    org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:5.4.3
    container_name: grafana
    volumes:
    - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
    - ./grafana/datasources:/etc/grafana/datasources
    - ./grafana/dashboards:/etc/grafana/dashboards
    - ./grafana/setup.sh:/setup.sh
    entrypoint: /setup.sh
    environment:
    - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER={ADMIN_USER}
    - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD={ADMIN_PASS}
    - GF_USERS_ALLOW_SIGN_UP=false
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
    - 3000:3000
    networks:
    - basic
    labels:
    org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"
```

When I `curl 0.0.0.0:9443/metrics` on my remote centos machine, I get all the list of metrics. However, when I run Prometheus with the above configuration, it throws the error `Get http://localhost:9443/metrics: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9443: connect: connection refused`. This is what my `prometheus.yml` looks like.

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 10s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']

  - job_name: 'peer_metrics'
    scrape_interval: 10s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9443']
```

Even, when I go to endpoint `http://localhost:9443/metrics` in my browser, I get all the metrics. What am I doing wrong here. How come Prometheus metrics are being shown on its interface and not peer's?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your prometheus container isn't running on host network. It's running on its own bridge (the one created by docker-compose). Therefore the scrape config for peer should point at the IP of the peer container.

Recommended way of solving this:

- Run prometheus and grafana in the same network as the fabric network.
  In you docker-compose for prometheus stack you can reference it like this:

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: <your-hyperledger-network>
```

(use `docker network ls` to find the network name )

Then you can use `http://<peer_container_name>:9443` in your scrape config

Comment: I've added prometheus and grafana configuration in docker-compose.yml itself. i added networks: basic: driver: bridge at the top. Prometheus is working fine. The targets are up when seen on the prometheus interface. However when I'm adding datasource http://localhost:9443 in grafana, it says HTTP Bad error Gateway.

Comment: Upon adding networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: basic
in docker-compose.yml, I'm getting errror 'Network basic declared as external, but could not be found. Please create the network manually using `docker network create basic` and try again.'

Comment: On inspecting network by doing docker network inspect <network-name>, I can see prometheus and grafana containers part of the same network as other fabric containers are.

Comment: The network used by the "basic-network" sample fabric is called "net_basic" (rather than "basic").

Comment: @KartikChauhan, if they are on the same network, then again - you need to scrape not on the localhost but on peer container service name.

Comment: @KartikChauhan in Grafana you should be adding only the prometheus as data source - i.e prometheus:9090

Comment: @antweiss Yes, I'm doing exactly what you said here
I've added this in prometheus.yml
- job_name: 'peer_metrics'
    scrape_interval: 10s
    static_configs:
        - targets: ['peer0.org1.example.com:9443']

I'm getting the targets up in prometheus interface but when I create datasource with url http:localhost:9090 in grafana, I don't see any graph for peer or chaincode.

Comment: @KartikChauhan what's the query you're using in Grafana?

Comment: Okay okay, I got it now, I had to import the dashboard in order to see the graphs.

Comment: @antweiss Just one more favor, could you tell how can i import the dashboard used on this page these guys https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-12872?attachmentSortBy=dateTime. Please have a look at the screenshot. I couldn't find this one in grafana available dashboards.

Comment: @KartikChauhan as far as I can tell - there is no dashboard to import there. You'll have to create your own dashboards by inputting prometheus queries for the metrics you're interested in. Something like : ```ledger_blockchain_height(channel="mychannel", instance="peer0.org1.example.com:9443")```

Answer (score 64):

Since the targets are not running inside the prometheus container, they cannot be accessed through localhost. You need to access them through the host private IP or by replacing `localhost` with `docker.for.mac.localhost` or `host.docker.internal`.

On Windows:

- `host.docker.internal` (*tested on win10, win11*)

On Max

- `docker.for.mac.localhost`

Comment: you should use only `host.docker.internal`.

`docker.for.mac.localhost` and `docker.for.win.localhost` are deprecated.

Comment: Wow, this really saved me after hours of searching. Thank you very much.

Comment: Confirmed `host.docker.internal` works in macOS 14.3, Docker Desktop 4.25.2

Answer (score 22):

**The problem**: On Prometheus you added a service for scraping but on `http://localhost:9090/targets` the endpoint state is **Down**
with an error:

> Get http://localhost:9091/metrics: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9091: connect:
> connection refused

[image]

**Solution**: On `prometheus.yml` you need to verify that

1. scraping details pointing to the right endpoint.
2. the yml indentation is correct.
3. using `curl -v http://<serviceip>:<port>/metrics` should prompt the metrics in plaintext in your terminal.

**Note**: If you pointing to some service in another docker container, your localhost might be represented not as localhost but as `servicename` ( service name that shown in `docker ps` ) or `docker.host.internal` (the internal ip that running the docker container ).

**for this example:** I'll be working with 2 dockers containers prometheus and "myService".

```
sudo docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     CREATED                        PORTS                    NAMES
abc123        prom/prometheus:latest        2 hours ago               0.0.0.0:9090->9090/tcp         prometheus
def456        myService/myService:latest         2 hours ago               0.0.0.0:9091->9091/tcp         myService
```

and then edit the file `prometheus.yml` (and rerun prometheus)

```
- job_name: myService
  scrape_interval: 15s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  static_configs:
    - targets: // Presenting you 3 options
      - localhost:9091 // simple localhost 
      - docker.host.internal:9091 // the localhost of agent that runs the docker container
      - myService:9091 // docker container name (worked in my case)
```

Comment: On Linux - myService:9090 could be the preferred way

Comment: Thanks. docker container name worked for me

Comment: `host.docker.internal` and `container name` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

*NOTE

This solution is not for **docker swarm**. It for standalone containers (multi-container) aimed to be run on **overlay** network.*

The same error we get when using **overlay** network and here is the solution (statically NOT dynamically)

this config does not work:

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

  external_labels:
    monitor: 'promswarm'

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']

  - job_name: 'node'
    static_configs:
      - targets: [ 'localhost:9100' ]
```

Nor does this one even when http://docker.for.mac.localhost:9100/ is available, yet **prometheus** cannot find **node-exporter**. So the below one did not work either:

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

  external_labels:
    monitor: 'promswarm'

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']


  - job_name: 'node'
    static_configs:
      - targets: [ 'docker.for.mac.localhost:9100'  ]
```

But simply using its container ID we can have access to that service via its port number.

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES
a58264faa1a4   prom/prometheus          "/bin/prometheus --c…"   5 minutes ago    Up 5 minutes    0.0.0.0:9090->9090/tcp, :::9090->9090/tcp   unruffled_solomon
62310f56f64a   grafana/grafana:latest   "/run.sh"                42 minutes ago   Up 42 minutes   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp   wonderful_goldberg
7f1da9796af3   prom/node-exporter       "/bin/node_exporter …"   48 minutes ago   Up 48 minutes   0.0.0.0:9100->9100/tcp, :::9100->9100/tcp   intelligent_panini
```

So we have `7f1da9796af3   prom/node-exporter` ID and we can update our `yml` file to:

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

  external_labels:
    monitor: 'promswarm'

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']


  - job_name: 'node'
    static_configs:
      - targets: [ '7f1da9796af3:9100'  ]
```

#### not working

[image]

#### working

[image]

---

#### UPDATE

I myself was not happy with this hard-coded solution , so after some other search found a more reliable approach using `--network-alias NAME` which within the **overlay** network , that container will be route-able by that name. So the `yml` looks like this:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']


  - job_name: 'node'
    static_configs:
      - targets: [ 'node_exporter:9100' ]
```

In which the name `node_exporter` is an alias which has been created with `run` subcommand. e.g.

```
docker run --rm  -d  -v "/:/host:ro,rslave" --network cloud --network-alias node_exporter --pid host -p 9100:9100   prom/node-exporter  --path.rootfs=/host
```

And in a nutshell it says on the overlay **cloud** network you can reach node-exporter using `node_exporter:<PORT>`.

Answer (score 0):

Well I remember I resolved the problem by downloading Prometheus node exporter for windows.

check out this link https://medium.com/@facundofarias/setting-up-a-prometheus-exporter-on-windows-b3e45f1235a5

Answer (score 0):

*If you pointing to some service in another docker container, your localhost might be represented not as localhost but as servicename ( service name that shown in docker ps ) or internal ip that running the docker container* .

**prometheus.yaml**

```yaml
 - job_name: "node-exporter"

    static_configs:
      - targets: ["nodeexporter:9100"] // docker container name
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I got this error because kubeprostack pods like prometheus in AKS are also running. When I scaled down the pods related to kubeprostack in the "deployments" and "deamonsets" sections of AKS to 1, the problem was solved and I was able to successfully connect to Grafana Prometheus. Because both prometheus and kubeprostack were trying to work. Problem solved when only prometheus pods remained.

[Post-procedure status image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfEYK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Run both the containers in the same network of docker it will fix the issue.

[image: success log]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).