# Prometheus (in Docker container) Cannot Scrape Target on Host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus

Prometheus running inside a docker container (*version 18.09.2, build 6247962*, `docker-compose.xml` below) and the scrape target is on `localhost:8000` which is created by a Python 3 script.

Error obtained for the failed scrape target (`localhost:9090/targets`) is

> Get http://127.0.0.1:8000/metrics: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8000: getsockopt: connection refused

**Question:** Why is Prometheus in the docker container unable to scrape the target which is running on the host computer (Mac OS X)? How can we get Prometheus running in docker container able to scrape the target running on the host?

**Failed attempt:** Tried replacing in `docker-compose.yml`

```
networks: 
  - back-tier
  - front-tier
```

with

```
network_mode: "host"
```

but then we are unable to access the Prometheus admin page at `localhost:9090`.

Unable to find solution from similar questions

- [Getting error "Get http://localhost:9443/metrics: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9443: connect: connection refused"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54397463/getting-error-get-http-localhost9443-metrics-dial-tcp-127-0-0-19443-conne)

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.3'

networks:
  front-tier:
  back-tier:

services:

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.1.0
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/prometheus:/etc/prometheus/
      - ./prometheus/prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries'
      - '--web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles'
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    networks:
      - back-tier
    restart: always


  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    user: "104"
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./grafana/grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
      - ./grafana/provisioning/:/etc/grafana/provisioning/
    env_file:
      - ./grafana/config.monitoring
    networks:
      - back-tier
      - front-tier
    restart: always
```

**prometheus.yml**

```
global:
scrape_interval:     15s 
evaluation_interval: 15s 

external_labels:
    monitor: 'my-project'

- job_name: 'prometheus'

    scrape_interval: 5s

    static_configs:
        - targets: ['localhost:9090']


- job_name: 'rigs-portal'

    scrape_interval: 5s

    static_configs:
        - targets: ['127.0.0.1:8000']
```

**Output at `http://localhost:8000/metrics`**

```
# HELP python_gc_objects_collected_total Objects collected during gc
# TYPE python_gc_objects_collected_total counter
python_gc_objects_collected_total{generation="0"} 65.0
python_gc_objects_collected_total{generation="1"} 281.0
python_gc_objects_collected_total{generation="2"} 0.0
# HELP python_gc_objects_uncollectable_total Uncollectable object found during GC
# TYPE python_gc_objects_uncollectable_total counter
python_gc_objects_uncollectable_total{generation="0"} 0.0
python_gc_objects_uncollectable_total{generation="1"} 0.0
python_gc_objects_uncollectable_total{generation="2"} 0.0
# HELP python_gc_collections_total Number of times this generation was collected
# TYPE python_gc_collections_total counter
python_gc_collections_total{generation="0"} 37.0
python_gc_collections_total{generation="1"} 3.0
python_gc_collections_total{generation="2"} 0.0
# HELP python_info Python platform information
# TYPE python_info gauge
python_info{implementation="CPython",major="3",minor="7",patchlevel="3",version="3.7.3"} 1.0
# HELP request_processing_seconds Time spend processing request
# TYPE request_processing_seconds summary
request_processing_seconds_count 2545.0
request_processing_seconds_sum 1290.4869346540017
# TYPE request_processing_seconds_created gauge
request_processing_seconds_created 1.562364777766845e+09
# HELP my_inprorgress_requests CPU Load
# TYPE my_inprorgress_requests gauge
my_inprorgress_requests 65.0
```

**Python3 script**

```
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, Summary, Gauge
import random
import time

# Create a metric to track time spent and requests made
REQUEST_TIME = Summary("request_processing_seconds", 'Time spend processing request')

@REQUEST_TIME.time()
def process_request(t):
    time.sleep(t)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_http_server(8000)
    g = Gauge('my_inprorgress_requests', 'CPU Load')
    g.set(65)

    while True:
        process_request(random.random())
```

Comment: Have you tried to connect to `host.docker.internal:8000`?

Comment: Also, please post your docker version.

Comment: @AlexandreJuma Updated post with *version 18.09.2, build 6247962*. I tried going to `host.docker.internal:8000` in my browser but it shows an error *ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED*

Comment: I was asking if you tried to scrape `host.docker.internal:8000` from prometheus container.

Comment: @AlexandreJuma Yes you are right, scraping `host.docker.internal:8000` from pormetheus container works! Can prometheus access external IP addresses like `http://google.com:8000/metrics` for scraping?

Comment: Can you run `docker run ubuntu ping google.com`? Does it ping?

Comment: @AlexandreJuma `docker run ubuntu ping google.com` gave some errors. So I ran `docker exec -it -u root prometheus_1 /bin/sh` then `ping google.com` and it pings successfully! Can we conclude that it should work? Sorry for the silly docker questions

Comment: Yes, if you pinged `google.com` from within your container you tested 2 things: connectivity and DNS resolution. I agree all is working just fine :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: @DavidMaze Tried the accepted answer but did not work, as stated in original question. `host.docker.internal` solution in the same SO question was not easily understandable to someone new to docker like myself. Alexandre's solution and comments was extremely clear.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

While not a very common use case.. you can indeed connect from your container to your host.

From https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/

> **I want to connect from a container to a service on the host**
>
> The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network
>   access). From 18.03 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the
>   special DNS name **host.docker.internal**, which resolves to the internal
>   IP address used by the host. This is for development purpose and will
>   not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop for
>   Mac.

Comment: It was a solution for my case I use docker version v19.03, thank you.

Answer (score 16):

Below is an example of running Prometheus on Docker for macOS which causes Prometheus to scrape a simple Spring Boot application running on `localhost:8080`:

**Bash**

```
docker run --rm --name prometheus -p 9090:9090 -v /Users/YourName/conf/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml -d prom/prometheus
```

**/Users/YourName/conf/prometheus.yml**

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s 
  evaluation_interval: 15s 

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'spring-boot'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['host.docker.internal:8080']
```

In this case it is the use of the special domain `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost` that causes the host to be resolved from the container on a macOS as the config file is mapped into the Prometheus container.

**Environment**

- Macbook Pro, Apple M1 Pro
- Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701
- Prometheus 2.38

Comment: What has also worked for me is: As we want to run Prometheus in a Docker container we need to tell Prometheus our IP address instead of localhost.
`
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - '192.168.1.100:8080'
`

Comment: Added ip address and host.docker.internal in the prometheus yml file. Still the state remains down. I am using windows machine.- targets: - '10.166.173.153:8080' - 'host.docker.internal:8080'

Comment: i would like to simply scrape the host name - without having to relabel. is that possible?

Comment: host.docker.internal worded perfectly !

Answer (score 6):

For reference for people who might find this question through search, this is supported now as of Docker 20.10 and above. See the following link:

[How to access host port from docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container/43541732#43541732)

and:

https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264#issuecomment-823528103

Answer (score 0):

i have used host.docker.internal to access the service inside the docker-compose file but it does not work i think you need to add

--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway

you can check the response here
[How to access host port from docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container/43541732#43541732)

bu the easy way for me was using the IP address (if you are using ubuntu use this command "ifconfig") or the server name as target for my Prometheus service in the prometheus.yaml

- targets:
  - your-ip-address:8000