# Is it possible to configure prometheus in a docker container to scrape a target on docker host?

Tags: docker, prometheus, docker-for-windows

I would like to scrape a target on my docker host. I either get 404 or conection refused.

My question is pretty much the same as this one here:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56909896/prometheus-in-docker-container-cannot-scrape-target-on-host](http://My%20question%20is%20pretty%20much%20the%20same%20as%20this%20one%20here:%20%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56909896/prometheus-in-docker-container-cannot-scrape-target-on-host)

But the accepted answer (**host.docker.internal:XXXX**) did not work for me :/

I am working on a Docker for Windows environment with linux container.

Comment: Can you ping `host.docker.internal` from within the docker container?

Comment: Good idea, I tested it and the ping works!
But why does it not work then? :/

Comment: Do you get the metrics when accessing `_system/metrics` or the endpoint you configured?

Comment: Yes, my metrics endpoint is available under:

http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Fixed it:

I missed to specify my actual metrics enpoint in prometheus.yaml

Then:

```
  - job_name: 'spring-exporter'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['host.docker.internal:8080']
```

Now:

```
  - job_name: 'spring-exporter'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['host.docker.internal:8080']
```