# Prometheus target is showing down

Tags: node.js, express, prometheus

### Target server

I built a target server in express-js.

```js
const express = require("express");
var morgan = require("morgan");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

let counter = 10;

app.use(morgan("combined"));

app.get("/metrics", (req, res) => {
  counter += 10;
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
  res.send(`CUSTOM_SERVER_COUNTER ${counter}`);
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

### Prometheus

Configures my target in the Prometheus and it's showing in the UI also.
[image]

Not sure why my target is always showing down.

Comment: It seems you might need to enable TCP connection i.e you might need to move it to https to make it work.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara port 9090 is also working on HTTP which is default HTTP server of prometheus

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54397463/getting-error-get-http-localhost9443-metrics-dial-tcp-127-0-0-19443-conne) helps?

Comment: The issue is solved, my express server was running on my system host and Prometheus was running inside docker. 

So, it wasn’t express server wasn’t accessible from inside the docker..

Comment: @Rahul How were you able to solve this issue? I too have a requirement where my service is running in local and the prometheus was running in docker.

Comment: I used host networking, for more info see https://docs.docker.com/network/host/