# Prometheus not connecting to OpenTelemetry Collector

Tags: docker, .net-core, prometheus, open-telemetry

I'm trying to send metrics from my .NET 7 application to Prometheus. Since I am working with a .NET service instead of a ASP.NET Core app, the way to do this is by using the OTLP exporter and using the OpenTelemetry Collector, [As stated by OpenTelemetry](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/net/exporters/#prometheus-experimental) Here is the `config.yaml` for opentelemetry collector

```
# /tmp/otel-collector-config.yaml
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      http:
      grpc:

exporters:
  logging:
    loglevel: debug
  prometheus:
    namespace: "otel"
    endpoint: "localhost:6666" # what port?
processors:
  batch:
service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [logging]
      processors: [batch]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [logging, prometheus]
      processors: [batch]
```

Here is my `prometheus.yml`

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
        - targets:
          # - alertmanager:9093

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: "prometheus"

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:9090"]

  - job_name: 'opentelemetry-collector'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['docker.for.mac.localhost:6666'] # what port?
```

The way I start my opentelemtry collector is by running `docker run -p 4317:4317 -v $(pwd)/config.yaml:/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml otel/opentelemetry-collector:latest --config=/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml`.

The way I start prometheus is by running `docker run -p 9090:9090 -v /Users/VMCR87/Code/prometheus_config/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml prom/prometheus`

When I start up prometheus, I get an error for my opentelemetry target, stating that `Get "http://docker.for.mac.localhost:6666/metrics": dial tcp 192.168.65.2:6666: connect: connection refused`. Here is a screenshot

[image]

I suspect this is an issue with the targets not running inside my container, I have read some suggestions [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54397463/getting-error-get-http-localhost9443-metrics-dial-tcp-127-0-0-19443-conne) but those have not worked.

How exactly should I be running the collector and prometheus together so that prometheus can read metrics being sent from my application?

Comment: Maybe using Docker Compose would be easier for a couple of components working together. You could look at the example in https://github.com/mhausenblas/o11y-in-action.cloud/tree/main/code/ch11/metrics-traces specifically `docker-compose.yaml`, `otel-config.yaml`, and `prometheus.yml`.